# Symfony 1.4 functional testing pre selected option in select tag

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have a certain response page which contains a form with a < select> tag with certain < options>, and one of them previously selected.

Is there a way to functionally test that certain option has been selected by default in this response?

I tried to use the checkElement of the response tester, but I can't find a way to use it for selected options in this tag...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
$browser->
  with('response')->begin()->
    checkElement('select#yourselect option[value="whatevervalue"][selected="selected"]')->
  end()
;
```